# WinExec with start command gives ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: windows, winapi

In my application, users can store a command to be run at a certain point. Right now, someone added "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://www.google.com". This is invoked by using the WinExec function. Now, when this command is changed to "start http://www.google.com", the function returns an ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, while it seems this should work from examples I find online.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I did not write the code using WinExec (it's 10 years old) so I'm not going to change it just for this.

Comment: If you are changing the code, surely it's easier to call ShellExecute?

Comment: The user can just change the command to be run from "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://www.google.com" to "cmd.exe /c start http://www.google.com" in the user interface.

Comment: OK, I see. I assumed that the command was part of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WinExec` is for starting processes. But what you are trying to do is best done by asking the shell to work out which program is associated with `http://` and display the URL with that. What you need to do is call `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx`.

For example:

```
ShellExecute(0, NULL, "http://www.google.com", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

The reason that `start` does not work with `WinExec` is that `start` is not an executable. It's a built in command handled by the interpreter, `cmd.exe`. So you could use `WinExec` if you passed `cmd.exe` (or the value of the `COMSPEC` environment variable) and got `cmd.exe` to call `start`. But that's the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

The command should be:

```
cmd.exe /c start http://www.google.com
```

and you shoudn't use [`WinExec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), read the note:

> Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit
>   Windows. Applications should use the [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

if you use `WinExec` for opening URLs, use [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by passing `open` to `lpOperation` insted:

```
ShellExecute(NULL,
             TEXT("open"),
             TEXT("http://www.google.com"),
             NULL,
             NULL,
             SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

The URL will be opened in the user default browser.

Comment: There's an echo in here ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What is about echo?

Comment: It's an idiomatic phrase. You're in a cave and say something. A second later you hear what you said as an echo.